# Bad full screen scaling when lowering the resolution

Tags: windows-8, laptop, windows-8.1, resolution, netbook

I have a Lenovo Z40 entertainment with Windows 8.1 with a resolution of 1920 x 1080 pixels, and I have to lower the resolution to play some games (because reasons), but now suddenly when I change the resolution to 1024 x 768 the screen goes like this:

[image]

Comment: What is the question?